# SQL: Converting dates to unique format

Tags: sql, date, format

Another question about date conversion in sql but haven't found any similar issue lol.

After joining a few DBs I have a

**column_x** nvarchar

with dates in the format *'dd/mm/yyyy'* and *'yyyy-mm-dd'*.

I would like to take all the values to the usual SQL format **'yyyy-mm-dd'** but nothing seems to work and I'm a bit stuck.
I tried with convert function but not working.

Also tried with **substring** to make 3 cols dd,mm,yyyy and join them as a proper date in a new column, but it keeps the ['/'] in so not solving the issue.

Thanks for help

Comment: What engine are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, Postgresql? etc. Please update your tag to include this. Also, when you say _joining a few DBs_ I assume you mean **tables** and that all of your table joins are in the same database?

Comment: Use proper **date** data type instead of nvarchar.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using SQL server, you can use a `CASE` statement to check the different formats and `CONVERT` it to a `DATE` type using the style that its currently in (read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)).

- Your *dd/mm/yyyy* format correlates to style code 103 (British
  French).
- Your *yyyy-mm-dd* format correlates to style code 23    (ISO8601).

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN column_x LIKE '%-%-%' THEN CONVERT(DATE, column_x, 23)
     WHEN column_x LIKE '%/%/%' THEN CONVERT(DATE, column_x, 103)
     ELSE NULL
END AS column_x
FROM sampletAble
```

**Input:**

```
| column_x    |
|-------------|
| 30/10/2022  |
| 2022-10-31  |
```

**Output:**

```
| column_x    |
|-------------|
| 2022-10-30  |
| 2022-10-31  |
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/RIRZdzAL).

As mentioned in the comments above, the **best** solution would be changing the `NVARCHAR` column data type to `DATE`.